# Finding the elements common among two sorted vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I need to write a function, which takes const references to vectors, and returns an ascending vector, of numbers.

I have two sorted vectors of integers as arguments, and need to find all common elements **using only the `<vector>` header**.

Any ideas for that? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Using only headers?  What does that mean?  In `<algotithm>` you can find `set_intersection` that does this _for the most part_

Comment: can't use algorithm, only can use header vector

Comment: Are you saying your function should merge two sorted vectors of integers into one sorted vector?

Comment: no, the function should return sorted vector with only common elements.

Comment: so v1 {1, 5, 6} v2 {4, 5, 9} so function should return returnVector {5}

Comment: OK, so take programming out of the equation.  Let's say you had two stacks of playing cards, sorted.  How would _you_ fix this problem?  Figure out _what_ to do (the algorithm) then translate it to code.

Comment: @System you can still look at the implementations in `<algorithm>` to get an idea of how things are done, then apply that logic to your own code.

Comment: Are you asking "how do I implement `set_intersection`"?

Comment: hmmm so only way to that is to create my own algorithm and write it ? ok guys, thank you ! Closed topic :) now I know what to do !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the elements are in order, you only have to pass over them once.

With iterators to each, carry on if neither range is at the end

If neither element are less than the other, then they are equal, and you can write one to the result.

Otherwise, you need to advance the iterator pointing to the smaller element.

See the possible implementation of [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)

> ```
> template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt>
> OutputIt set_intersection(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
>                           InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
>                           OutputIt d_first)
> {
>     while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
>         if (*first1 < *first2) {
>             ++first1;
>         } else  {
>             if (!(*first2 < *first1)) {
>                 *d_first++ = *first1++;
>             }
>             ++first2;
>         }
>     }
>     return d_first;
> }
> ```

Let's adapt it to the "nothing but `<vector>`" rule

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> set_intersection(const std::vector<T> & one, const std::vector<T> & two)
{
    std::vector<T> result;

    std::vector<T> const_iterator first1 = one.begin(), last1 = one.end(), first2 = two.begin(), last2 = two.end();

    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
        if (*first1 < *first2) {
            ++first1;
        } else  {
            if (!(*first2 < *first1)) {
                result.push_back(*first1++);
            }
            ++first2;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Caleths answer is absolutely valid, you might be a beginner and might want a simpler way to do it (For learning the language and so on).

Which would be:

```
std::vector<int> find_same_ints(const std::vector<int> &vec1, const std::vector<int> &vec2)
{
    std::vector<int> results;

    //Check if same number exists in the both vector arguments, if so, push the number to results
    for(int x : vec1)
        for(int y : vec2)
            if(x == y)
                results.push_back(x);

    //Simple bubblesort algorithm
    for(std::size_t x = 0; x < results.size(); x++)
    {
        int lowestValueIndex = x;

        //Try to find the lowest value of the remaining not sorted values
        for(std::size_t y = x + 1; y < results.size(); y++)
            if(results[y] < results[lowestValueIndex])
                lowestValueIndex = y;

        //Swap the values
        int temp = results[lowestValueIndex];
        results[lowestValueIndex] = results[x];
        results[x] = temp;
    }

    //Return sorted vector
    return results;
}
```

Keep in mind Caleths algorithm is the one you should use when you gain experience in the language and understand what is actually going on in the code.

Comment: ok ! Thank you so much :) and yes ! Im beginner and I heard the opinions that algorithms are very very very important. I will keep that in mind. :)